# How to create a link to python3 on MacOS?

Tags: macos, terminal, python

Running MacOS 13.1 (Ventura) I see that `python3` is installed in `/usr/bin`, which I can call by running `python3`. However, I also want to run `python3` by just calling `python`, so I changed to the folder `/usr/bin` and run the command

```
sudo ln -s python3 python
```

which ended in the error

```
ln: python: Operation not permitted
```

Maybe I need more than `root` rights, or what weird Mac thing is going on?

However, what to do to link `python` to `python3`?

Comment: `/usr/bin/` is part of the read-only system volume. You can't add, delete or modify anything there.

Comment: It seems that you can't even create a link from `/some/other/directory/python` to `/usr/bin/python3`. Well, you can create a link, but then running `/some/other/directory/python` fails, at least for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you cannot.

The simplest solution is to create an alias for python. In you ~/.zprofile file add

```
alias python='/usr/bin/python3'
```

This means that when you type python you get python3. However you can't run a python script with `#! /usr/bin/env python` as the first line, which I think is good as you should make that explicitly python3.

However if you are using python heavily then the general opinion is not to use Apple's python but to install it from elsewhere. I would recommend from [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) (or pay for anaconda if doing this professionally) or from [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/). Alternatively via a package manager e.g. MacPorts, Homebrew nix.

The reason you cannot change or add things in /usr/bin in modern version of macOS is that Apple puts most of the system onto a separate volume that cannot be written to and to enforce that it also checks that it has not been altered.